# Restaurar banco no sql server 2008 R2

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server

Tenho um aquivo .bak e ao tentar restaurar estou utilizando o seguinte comando:

```
use [master]
RESTORE DATABASE Teste FROM DISK='C:\Teste.BAK'
```

Mas o sql me retorna a seguinte mensagem:

```
Msg 3241, Level 16, State 13, Line 2
The media family on device 'C:\Teste.BAK' is incorrectly formed. SQL Server cannot process this media family.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

Comment: Em que servidor foi feito esse backup? Já tentou restaura-lo no servidor de origem?

Comment: Resolvido!!! O arquivo .BAK foi gerado em um SQL server 2012, e eu estava tentando levantar o banco em um SQL 2008.